# CapturedPhoto.Frame.SoftwareBitmap is null

Tags: c#, camera, win-universal-app, capture

I am trying to use [AdvancedPhotoCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.prepareadvancedphotocaptureasync) to get a SoftwareBitmap but the resulting CapturedPhoto.Frame.SoftwareBitmap is null. How can I get a SoftwareBitmap so I can display it to screen?

```
//create mediacapture
mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();

// check if supported
var settings = new AdvancedPhotoCaptureSettings
{
    Mode = AdvancedPhotoMode.Standard
};

//configure capture
if (!mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.AdvancedPhotoControl.SupportedModes.Contains(settings.Mode))
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Mode not supported");
    return;
}
mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.AdvancedPhotoControl.Configure(settings);
var adv = await mediaCapture.PrepareAdvancedPhotoCaptureAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg());

// take photo
var capturedPhoto = await adv.CaptureAsync();
Debug.WriteLine(capturedPhoto.Frame.SoftwareBitmap == null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg()
```

with

```
ImageEncodingProperties.CreateUncompressed(MediaPixelFormat.Bgra8)
```

For AdvancedPhotoCapture, VariablePhotoSequence, LowLagCaptureSequence, etc. the SoftwareBitmap will only be populated when encoding with an uncompressed format.